# gnuplot fit line to two points

Tags: gnuplot

Consider the data file with two columns and two rows:

```
  3869.    1602.  
  3882.    9913.
```

I'd like to fit a line using gnuplot

```
gnuplot> f(x) = a * x + b
gnuplot> fit f(x) './data.txt' u 1:2 via a, b

Iteration 0
WSSR        : 3.43474e+07       delta(WSSR)/WSSR   : 0
delta(WSSR) : 0                 limit for stopping : 1e-05
lambda   : 2740.4

initial set of free parameter values

a               = 1.7524
b               = -1026.99
/

Iteration 1
WSSR        : 3.43474e+07       delta(WSSR)/WSSR   : -1.49847e-12
delta(WSSR) : -5.14686e-05      limit for stopping : 1e-05
lambda   : 274.04

resultant parameter values 

a               = 1.7524
b               = -1026.99

After 1 iterations the fit converged.
final sum of squares of residuals : 3.43474e+07
rel. change during last iteration : -1.49847e-12


Exactly as many data points as there are parameters.
In this degenerate case, all errors are zero by definition.

Final set of parameters 
======================= 

a               = 1.7524         
b               = -1026.99       
gnuplot>
```

which gives wrong values for fit parameters. Why is this happening? My gnuplot version is `Version 4.4 patchlevel 0`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that the curve-fitting function is struggling to find the true parameters. This could be associated with the magnitude of your data points and/or trying to fit a line with two parameters to only two data points.

In any case, doing the calculation of a and b in Excel or equivalent yields:

```
a= 577.769
b = -2233787
```

If you give gnuplot a good guess at what they should be, e.g. `a=500` and `b=-2233700` and repeat the procedure, it should successfully find the correct solution:

```
Final set of parameters 
======================= 

a               = 577.769        
b               = -2.23379e+06
```

Of course, if you're fitting two points to a two-parameter straight line, it's much easier to calculate the values of `a` and `b` by hand:

```
a = (9113-1602) / (3882-3869)
b = 1602 - a * 3869
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What do you mean saying: "magnitude of your data points"?

Comment: Gnuplot makes a first guess on the parameters (a=1.75, b=-1027) if one is unsupplied and iterates on these to get the true solution. In this case it looks like due to the relative sizes (i.e. magnitude) of your data points (1600-9000) the first guess that gnuplot makes is particularly bad, causing the fit function to fail.

Comment: The thing is that for `(3869., 1.)` and `(3870., 2.)` it also fails and the differences are much smaller.

Answer (score 1):

Gnuplot uses a non-linear method to determine the parameters of your function `f` with respect to a certain error value: `limit for stopping : 1e-05`.

If you change that error value your function will be exactly fit. The error value can be specified with the `FIT_LIMIT` variable like so:

```
FIT_LIMIT = 1e-8
```

With this setting your points will be exactly matched after 12 iterations. (At least on my machine^^)